# Resource leak in http call execution

Tags: java, android, android-strictmode, resource-leak

I am receiving the below error message when I execute this code.

**A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.:**

I am unable to identify the resource leak in the below code. I'll be greatful if anyone point out what actually I am doing wrong.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString);
        entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = getHttpClientImpl();

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception se) {
            Log.e("Exception", se + "");
            throw se;
        } finally {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();

            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();

            if (client != null && client.getConnectionManager() != null) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see any issues with that code, but I recommend closing all the idle connections in the pool.

```
public abstract void closeIdleConnections (long idletime, TimeUnit tunit)
```

Furthermore, there are some known issues with the DefaultHttpClient when not entirely configured correctly. I recommend using the AndroidHttpClient as an implementation of the HttpClient interface. Visit following documentation for the explanation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html